# laravel JWT token can be used just once and it gets invalid token on second try

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I am using JWT token and it worked fine sometime ago. But now when ever I use the token I get the result I want in first try and I check it for the second time (after 2 minutes) and I get invalid token:
This is my authenticate code:

```
  $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    try {
        // verify the credentials and create a token for the user
        if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        // something went wrong
        return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
    }

    // if no errors are encountered we can return a JWT
    return response()->json(compact('token'));
```

And this is my web.php file

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1','middleware' => ['cors']], function(){

Route::resource('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController');
Route::post('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController@authenticate');
Route::group(['middleware' => ['jwt.auth', 'jwt.refresh']], function() {
    Route::resource('books', 'BooksController', ['except'=>'store', 'update']);
});
```

});

Comment: Are you storing `token` created  ? in your local storage or cookies

Comment: I don't think so, how can I check that?

Comment: did you changed token lifetime in `config/jwt.php` ?

Comment: You mean ttl? It is 60 the default value

Comment: @DrStein yes. ttl is lifetime. default 60 min .

Comment: I am not getting, how you authenticated user, 1. in each request by sending username/password or 2. storing token in first request and use that token in next request,so where you are storing token and how. I know only these two method for JWT, If you are using any other please share with us ?

Comment: After I login I get token, and with each request I send token with the url (as  parameter)

Comment: Everything looks fine, except you sent wrong token or expired token. How you check you token is expired or not  ? you can include all detail in your question , it will be clear to other.

Comment: Excluding token encryption in cookies maybe?

Comment: Why you are encrypting token ? use as it is

Comment: I send the same token, but it works once. And the token shouldn't be expired in 2 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using refresh tokens (jwt.refresh middleware) this is the intended behavior.

https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Authentication

> This middleware will again try to parse the token from the request, and in turn will refresh the token (thus invalidating the old one) and return it as part of the next response. This essentially yields a single use token flow, which reduces the window of attack if a token is compromised, since it is only valid for the single request.

If you don't want to use refresh tokens, then you can just drop that middleware. If you do want to use refresh tokens, you will need to update the token you use for authentication on every request.